# How do I Access Items of a Listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have a Listbox done like this

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbAlbumSelect">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                            <Button>
                                    <Button.Content>
                                        <StackPanel>
                                        <Image />
                                            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                                                           Text="{Binding album_name}" />
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Button.Content>
                                </Button>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I want to access every `Image` programmatically and set its `Source`. I tried to navigate the listbox like this

```
foreach (Button btn in lbAlbumSelect.Items)
           {
               StackPanel stack=btn.Content;
               Image image=stack.Children.ElementAt(0) as Image;
               //every ListBoxItem is binded to a clsAlbums object that contains various data, 
               //also the name of the image file, but not the path.
               string pathImg = @"/Assets/Images/" + (btn.DataContext as clsAlbums).album_img; 
               LoadImage(pathImg, image); //function that sets image source to path img
           }
```

But gives me a `Invalid Cast Exception` on the foreach clause.

Is there a faster and more correct way to do this?

Comment: Is items an array of buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ideally be binding the image source to the control. Add an additional property to your class clsAlbums which can be bound to the Image source.

```
public class clsAlbum
{
    public string album_name { get; set; }
    public string album_img { get; set; }
    public string album_img_src 
    {
        get
        {
             return @"/Assets/Images/" + album_img;
        }
    }
}
```

Now bind this additional property album_img_src to your xaml.

```
    <ListBox x:Name="lbAlbumSelect">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button>
                <Button.Content>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Image Source="{Binding album_img_src}"/>
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                                                    Text="{Binding album_name}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button.Content>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This works like a charm. But I'd still like to know how to navigate the listbox items programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

1. The item is actually ListBoxItem. In your case Button is content of ListBoxItem and Content of Button is StackPanel and Image is child of StackPanel. So you need to traverse visual tree somehow and you can do so using Linq to visual tree, for example. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/63157/LINQ-to-Visual-Tree
2. Probably easiest way of accessing elements inside datatemplate is from it's loaded or initialized event:

here:

```
<Image Loaded="Image_Loaded" />

void Image_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e){
    var image =(Image)sender;
```

3. Try to avoid acessing elements inside datatemplates. 90% times you achieve your goal better, using ViewModel, converters, using behaviours, datatriggers or extracting datatemplate to separate UserControl